# MSTEAMS BOT - post message to personalChat using rest api - Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

My objective is to post a message on `personalChat` in msteamsbot using restapi endpoint.

auth token is generated using below logic ([reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-to-connector))

```
    let url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    const data = { 
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' : '...',
        'client_secret' : '...',
        'scope' : 'https://api.botframework.com/.default'
    };
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      data: qs.stringify(data),
      url,
    };
    axios(options);
```

the token generated using above logic is passed to below api ([reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)). This api is supposed to post a message on the recipient's chat. but this doesn't happen.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/a:1NYEIhjRpL_RgDBDaA7lJyO6kl8rbpWQLyKkayQnZ_mKOZhnKAoeuiWEekt8vpjeoIcB3R394k6-zeC52sk60Q8ErZO5PIokS8ytjD-QK-CIJjIRaGg94KzTMz2d3XXjs/activities' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer authToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "type": "message",
    "recipient": {
        "id":"29:1dePA4jI3vyrUt-38_--KJxVeAg_v-XQVCBHcSxp4kgu7ZshPPSbsbSOZ7m-GAKK0IARbqyxg_bit-IAt0J9d_w"
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "28:f4016730-f1ef-4fcd-9169-4159a2295591",
        "name": "Toolkit Bot - vTAPBotdemo"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "notification": {
            "alert": "true"
        }
    },
    "text": "Hello  "
}'
```

Below is the error message i receive when triggering the above api.
[image]
Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: Hi, so it looks like you're basically trying to create a request to send to your bot application so it thinks like it's coming from the bot service, right? if that's the case it should be, for all practical situations, just "impossible", as it would mean creating an valid token with the same signature as if it was created by the bot service. What are your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint i used to postMessage on `personal` chat is incorrect and it was present in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) as well.

Below is the correct endpoint. This endpoint can be seen by logging the http payload request body of `/api/messages` api

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{conversationid}/activities/{activityid}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer authToken' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "type": "message",
    "recipient": {
        "id":"29:1dePA4jI3vyrUt-38_--VeAgKJx_v-CBHXQVcSxp4kgu7ZshPPSbsbSOZ7m-GAKK0IARbqyxg_bit-IAt0J9d_w"
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "28:f4016730-f1ef-4fcd-9169-4159a2295591",
        "name": "Toolkit Bot - vTAPBotdemo"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "notification": {
            "alert": "true"
        }
    },
    "text": "Hello  "
}'
```